# AutoFixture: specify boundaries (or set as "now") for all random dates generated

Tags: .net, nunit, autofixture

I have a need to tell AutoFixture that all random dates it generates should be within certain limit, or, for instance, equal to Now. I would like just to set behaviour of Fixture instance so it applies to all use cases throughout the code, that I do not want to examine individually.

How I could configure AutoFixture to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to return the same `DateTime` value all over the object graph just inject the desired value to the `fixture`:

```
fixture.Inject(DateTime.Now);
```

If you need values to be in a specific range though, add the customization like this:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new RandomDateTimeSequenceGenerator(
        minDate: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15),
        maxDate: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15)
    ));
```